# MacOS: How to install puppeteer with or without Chromium?

Tags: macos, npm, chromium, puppeteer

I am trying to install puppeteer globally on macOS (Mojave) 10.14.3

1. First failure (in `sudo su` mode): `npm install -g puppeteer`

```
> puppeteer@1.12.2 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/puppeteer
> node install.js

ERROR: Failed to download Chromium r624492! Set "PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD" env variable to skip download.
{ Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium'
  -- ASYNC --
    at BrowserFetcher.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:108:27)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/puppeteer/install.js:64:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:743:3)
  errno: -13,
  code: 'EACCES',
  syscall: 'mkdir',
  path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium' }
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! puppeteer@1.12.2 install: `node install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the puppeteer@1.12.2 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /var/root/.npm/_logs/2019-02-27T14_04_04_609Z-debug.log
```

2. Second failure: I successfully installed manually Chromium from https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?prefix=Mac/635943/ and then (in `sudo su` mode):

`npm get | grep PUPPETEER`

```
PUPPETEER_EXECUTABLE_PATH = "/Applications/Chromium.app/Contents/MacOS/Chromium"
PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD = true
PUPPETEER_EXECUTABLE_PATH = "/Applications/Chromium.app/Contents/MacOS/Chromium"
PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD = true
```

`npm install -g puppeteer`

```
> puppeteer@1.12.2 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/puppeteer
> node install.js

ERROR: Failed to download Chromium r624492! Set "PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD" env variable to skip download.
{ Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium'
  -- ASYNC --
    at BrowserFetcher.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:108:27)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/puppeteer/install.js:64:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:743:3)
  errno: -13,
  code: 'EACCES',
  syscall: 'mkdir',
  path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium' }
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! puppeteer@1.12.2 install: `node install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the puppeteer@1.12.2 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /var/root/.npm/_logs/2019-02-27T14_07_19_001Z-debug.log
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: [main post edited]

Comment: `sudo node install.js`?

Comment: You should not globally install puppeteer. There is no reason to use it like that. What are you trying to achieve buy installing it globally?

Comment: @Md. Abu Taher
i) To avoid having 12 different installations of puppeteer for 12 different projects ; and
ii) To avoid having 12 different installations of chromium (probably each with a different build number) for 12 different projects.

Comment: You can try using `pnpm`, which will install one package only once in your whole computer and `symlink` it :) ..

Comment: Thanks @Md. Abu Taher, I didn't know `pnpm`, it looks pretty interesting indeed!

Comment: simply ```sudo npm install -g puppeteer --unsafe-perm=true```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try with it:

```
npm config set user 0
npm config set unsafe-perm true
npm install -g puppeteer
```

Option [unsafe-perm](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#unsafe-perm):

> Set to true to suppress the UID/GID switching when running package
> scripts. If set explicitly to false, then installing as a non-root
> user will fail.

> If npm was invoked with root privileges, then it will change the uid
> to the user account or uid specified by the user config, which
> defaults to nobody. Set the unsafe-perm flag to run scripts with root
> privileges.

Comment: The installation worked, thanks! But shouldn't we revert to the previous settings once the installation is done? `npm config delete user` and `npm config delete unsafe-perm`

Comment: this worked for me after many hours of testing of another answers! Thank you!

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me. I only had to use ```npm config set unsafe-perm true``` for me.

Answer (score 0):

This was working fine for me a matter of days ago, but am not getting exactly the same error